# My output is not being displayed to any of my projects in eclipse

Tags: java

after successful compilation of my project with no errors, am not getting the OUTPUT after clicking run. It is not being displayed.
please help me.

```
// Accept two strings and display how many characters in first strng are 
  present in second string
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CharacterCompare {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner s= new Scanner (System.in);
String Str1  = s.nextLine();
String Str2  = s.nextLine ();
int count = 0;
    for  (int i=0; i<Str1.length(); i++)
       {
                for (int j=0; j<Str2.length();j++)
                {
                    if (Str1.charAt(i)==Str2.charAt(j)) {
                        count ++;
                        break;
                    }

                }
       }
    System.out.println(count);
}
}
```

Comment: console output which should be displayed at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Thanks! When you start your program, do you enter anything on the console? Your programm expects two lines of input after start, nothing would happen if you don't write anything.

Comment: It could be due to your settings to console window. If nothing other works, create a new workspace which will have default settings.

Comment: showing the error in the console:   [Invalid file specified for  stdin file: ]

Answer (score 0):

To show console in eclipse. Window -> Show View -> Console

The above program access 2 system inputs. After you give second input make sure you press Enter key.

Comment: tq now i can see console but getting an error : [Invalid file specified for  stdin file: ]